# WP - change usermeta value with metabox value via save_post hook

Tags: php, wordpress, action-hook

I have a CPT with 2 metaboxes. 1 = `mv_facility_code` 2 = `mv_facility_email`

All users have dB columns `user_facility` and `user_facility_email`

When a site admin goes into the CPT and changes the `mv_facility_email` I'm trying to find all users who's `user_facility` value matches `mv_facility_code` and change their metadata from the value in `user_facility_email` to the new `mv_facility_email`.

Here's what I'm trying, but it's not working.

```
add_action( 'save_post_cpt', 'mv_update_user_facility_details' );
function mv_update_user_facility_details() {

    $facility_code = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mv_facility_code', true);
    $facility_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mv_facility_email', true);

    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'user_facility',
        'meta_value' => $facility_code,
    );

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query();
    $users = $user_query->get_results();

    if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            update_user_meta( $user->user_id, 'user_facility_email', $facility_email );
        }
    };
};
```

Any help understanding my error is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some problems with your code. check this and read all comments

```
add_action( 'save_post_cpt', 'mv_update_user_facility_details' , 10  ,3 );

/**
 * @param WP_Post $post
 * passing all 3 parameter to function
 */

function mv_update_user_facility_details($post_id , $post, $update) {
if (! $update ) return;
$facility_code = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mv_facility_code', true);
//make sure this is the updated data
$facility_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mv_facility_email', true);

//args never used
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'user_facility',
    'meta_value' => $facility_code,
);
//pass it to constructor
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$users = $user_query->get_results();



//i prefer do it like this , same thing just easier to read 
$users = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'user_facility',
    'meta_value' => $facility_code,
]);

if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_facility_email', $facility_email );
    }
};
};
```

Comment: Thanks Shalior, I forgot to pass the `$args` when I abstracted the code, but it's done in the live version. `$facility_email ` is the updated data, I've confirmed by doing a search in my database for the new value and it shows up in postmeta - still not changing usermeta though.

Comment: Maybe `$user->user_id` in the `foreach` loop is not returning the user ID correctly? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: ywc, thats true, $user in loop is a WP_User object and id member is simply ID, its user_id in your code which returns null. changed that in my answer.

Comment: check this answer, logging really helps when debugging in wordpress:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260236/how-to-put-logs-in-wordpress

Comment: i also changed hook function based on 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/